# df size of partition and dd-ed image with sparse flag does not match

Tags: debian, disk-usage, dd

The size of a partition is close to 2Gb and the actual used size is 1.5Gb, I am trying to make image of this partition using `dd` with `conv=sparse` flag enabled.

The generated image by `dd` is of size 1.8Gb.

`du` shows that the actual used size of partition is 1.5Gb.

What puzzles me the most is that, earlier in the day, when I `dd`ed the partition it was what was showed by `du`. Then I made a couple of changes in the partition and then again ran `dd`. This time there was mismatch.

What caused this? My guess it that though the memory is free, it's not null/zero and so `dd`'s sparse algorithm does not work on it?

Comment: I have fixed some grammar/punctuation errors but I need help with “ it was what was showed by du”. Can you proof-read and fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. `dd` has no concept of filesystem usage, it just copies data (or not, if `conv=sparse` is set and the entire block is zero).

It's also possible to have a 100% full filesystem, and yet a tiny dd sparse image. Assuming your files are full of zeroes.

There's a difference between free space and intenionally zeroed but used space, but `dd` does not have a concept for that. So `conv=sparse` should be used with caution, especially on restore.

When restoring a sparse image with `conv=sparse`, the target device has to be fully zeroed, otherwise old non-zero data would remain where there is supposed to be zeroes. The result is a corrupt filesystem.

Comment: Some file-systems have a tool, to zero un-used blocks.